# How can I change Icon size in GTK applications?

Tags: icons, gtk

I'm on a HiDPI display and I can easily change text size on my applications with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 40
```

But that doesn't change the icon size, which remain tiny:

[image: Small icons]

There is a way to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scaling factor in "Settings" - "Displays". You can set 200% to double the overall size of the graphical elements. You could then eventually decrease the fonts a bit by decreasing the scaling factor.

If that does not work well, you still have the option to enable fractional scaling, but that requires extra processor power and may result in a less sharp image.

Comment: Can this be done through a terminal command?

Comment: These are all dconf settings, so yes.

Comment: This is not a suitable solution, as even though using scaling without fractional doesn't degrade quality, games detect resolution incorrectly when scaling is enabled, and I don't really have any need for enabling scaling apart from GTK tiny icons.